# KARMA Reference error:angular is not defined

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a asp.net mvc app . In Scripts I have the subfolder app containing Controller.js. I also have another subfolder Spec containint ControllerSpec.js - written with jasmine.

```
 describe('PhoneCat controllers', function () {
    beforeEach(module('phonecatApp'));

    describe('PhoneListCtrl', function () {

        it('should create "phones" model with 3 phones', inject(function ($controller) {
            var scope = {},
            ctrl = $controller('PhoneListCtrl', { $scope: scope });

            expect(scope.phones.length).toBe(3);
        }));
    });
});
```

In SpecRunner.cshtml i have just included this files:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/app/controllers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/Spec/controllersSpec.js"></script>
```

In karma init, I have added the path of those 2.js. 
Can you please tell me how can I do to make it work? If I run vs the Jasmine code it's ok.

Thx

Answer (score 1):

You must add a reference to angular.js as well

Comment: I added reference as: ../Scripts/ angular.js and the error still remains. I need to add reference in my Controller.js file?

Comment: Thre reference should be within your Karma config file. Can you add you config file + library structure?

Answer (score 1):

There could be a variety of reasons for such an error, so it would help to solve with a bit more info on your part.

However off hand and having seen this error before in my battles through angular unit testing, I have to ask are you including a link to angular-mocks.js?

The lastest repo: http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.15/

Angular Mocks: http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.15/angular-mocks.js

A copy of your karma.conf.js would also help....

Comment: I made it work adding refferences u said!!. thank you. // Karma configuration
'// Generated on Sat Mar 22 2014 22:08:45 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard
    files: [
      'AngTestProj/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js','AngTestProj/Scripts/angular.min.js','AngTestProj/Scripts/angular-mocks.js','AngTestProj/Scripts/app/*.js','AngTestProj/Scripts/Spec/*.js'
' I want to use **PHANTOMJS** but i cant make it work...cand u please tell me how can I do? I would like to know, for testing our spec: controller,directive...coult'd we use just jasmine and tes it with SpecRunner.cshtml?

Comment: Here is a copy of my karma.conf.js file we are using Phantom to test headless-ly. http://plnkr.co/edit/jh7LBYt0qAWIvpm4nL5o?p=catalogue

Comment: Also we are using grunt karma to run our unit tests - no more gui output just good ole command line text.

Comment: Thank you veru much for respone! Could you explain why you use also grunt? It's not enough to run just with karma? T

Comment: How about u accept that answer and I tell you... ;-)

Comment: Ahhh whatever this is a platform for knowledge sharing not for points gaining! Grunt... ahhh grunt... This is a tool i avoided learning for 6-9 months and i regret i waited so long. Simply put it makes your life easy, it takes the "grunt work" with a smile, it does your concatenation, minification, uglification, unit tests, E2E tests, server starting, build process, laundry, dishes, matches socks. Okay well maybe not the last 3 bits, but give it time... It's an awesome tool for all that shit you have to do but done wanna spend time doing it.

Comment: Can you tell I like it? http://gruntjs.com/ - Oh and don't forget: http://bower.io/ as well. It's the little white (colored) bird on the back of the pig pecking out all the bugs...

Comment: I see. thank you for your response! I also wanna ask pls, phantomjs..i use chrome for karma running. is phantomjs better?...

Comment: It's more or less the same just less overhead as u can run it from the command line.